# In Postman, received error "Illegal request-target: Invalid input '|', expected pchar, '/', '?' or 'EOI' (line 1, column 97)" when I call the API

Tags: postman

The API URL contains "|",
for example
https://xxxx/api/internal/trading/inspect/entities/XXXXEntity/12345678|CASH_ACCOUNT

Error msg:
Illegal request-target: Invalid input '|', expected pchar, '/', '?' or 'EOI' (line 1, column 97)

Answer (score 0):

| is one of the unsafe characters to use in URL. Unsafe characters have special meaning in the path component of the URL and some have special meaning in the query component.  To use | in URL you'll need to url-encode it ([URL Encoding of Special Characters](https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_9-1-0_SO_en/Content/SA_docs/API_Level_Integration/API_Integration_URLEncoding.html)), so instead of

```
https://xxxx/api/internal/trading/inspect/entities/XXXXEntity/12345678|CASH_ACCOUNT
```

use

```
https://xxxx/api/internal/trading/inspect/entities/XXXXEntity/12345678%7CCASH_ACCOUNT
```

Read more [Url special characters](https://www.abramillar.com/2018/01/15/special-characters-short-words-urls/) and [ietf](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) . See related question [special characters which are safe to use in url](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/498/which-special-characters-are-safe-to-use-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question if you do not want to change all your | to %7C

Go to postman setting - General - turn off "Use next-generation URL processing".
Then you can continue using | in the URL